# HTTParty double escapes my json

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, json, httparty

I have a few models in Ruby that I need to send to a Java/RestEasy server via HTTParty/Put.

configuration_mapping.rb:

```
def as_json(options = {})
  {:configGroup => @group, :coordinates => {@key => @value}}
end

def self.put(endpoint, content, tier = 'nursery')
  response = HTTParty.put(base_uri + endpoint, json_payload(content))
end    

def self.json_payload(content)
  {
    :body => content.to_json,
    :format => :json,
    :headers => {"Content-Type" => "application/json", "content-type" => "application/json", "Accept" => "application/json"}
  }
end
```

**The JSON gets double escaped:**

> { :body=>"   {
>         \"configGroup\":\"test\",
>         \"coordinates\":{
>            \"Integration Test Key\":\"moo\"
>         }    }   ", :format=>:json, :headers=>{"   Content-Type"=>"application/json",    "content-type"
>   =>"application/json",    "Accept"   =>"application/json" } }

And Jackson JSON parser borks:

> 2011-11-27 15:34:11,179 ERROR [tp-1442358158-0] [REPORT] []
>   [asy.core.SynchronousDispatcher] Failed executing PUT
>   /v1/groups/test/mappings;tester=Integration
>   Test;tier=qa;timeStamp=-4712-01-01
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ReaderException:
>   org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize
>   instance of java.lang.String out of START_OBJECT token  at [Source:
>   org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser$Input@4092fef5; line: 1, column: 22]     at

I tried letting httparty convert to json for me, thinking httparty escaped the characters, writing my own as_json method, but this is the output which is not the json I wanted, the wrong fields are in here and my as_json method is not called:

> {:body=>Config::Client::ConfigurationMapping:0x00000100c78930
>   @dimensions={"tester"=>"Integration Test", "tier"=>"qa",
>   "timeStamp"=>"-4712-01-01"}, @key="Integration Test Key",
>   @group="test", @value="moo">, :format=>:json,
>   :headers=>{"Content-Type"=>"application/json",
>   "content-type"=>"application/json", "Accept"=>"application/json"}}

What is causing the string to become double escaped?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem, my json wasn't formatted correctly. I reformatted the packet and it worked.